# Como utilizar la funcion .each en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy tratando de mostrar varios resultados de respuesta.seguimiento , consulte un poco y encontre que es con .each para que me muestre todo lo de ese campo , este es mi codigo..

```js
function Tcaso(id){ 
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{'id':id},
    dataType:'json',
    url: uri + "/caso/mostrarCasos",
   }).done(function(respuesta){
    $("#id").val(respuesta.id);
    console.log(id);
    $("#idcliente").val(respuesta.idcliente);
    $("#ncuentaca").val(respuesta.ncuenta);
    $("#nombreca").val(respuesta.nombre);
    $("#direccionca").val(respuesta.direccion);
    $("#telefonoca").val(respuesta.telefono);
    $("#ciudadca").val(respuesta.ciudad);
    $("#nombredecca").val(respuesta.nombredec);
                $("#fallaca").val(respuesta.falla);
                $("#descripcionca").val(respuesta.descripcion);
                $("#resca").val(respuesta.responsable);
                $("#fecca").val(respuesta.fecha);
                $("#estadoca").val(respuesta.estado);
                $("#solucionado").val(respuesta.solucion);
                $("#idseguimiento").val(respuesta.idseguimiento);
                $("#seguirme").val(respuesta.seguimiento);

    $("#modalT").modal();

    
  
   });
  }
```

Le quiero hacer un .each para que me muestre todo lo que tiene campo por que asì de momento me muestra solo un campo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me deberia mostrar examplito y big bank

```html
      <textarea type="textarea"  name="seguirme" id="seguirme"></textarea>

            <input type="text" name="idseguimiento" id="idseguimiento">
```

Esta es la consulta de mostrarCasos

```html
SELECT c.id, c.falla, c.responsable,  c.fecha ,c.descripcion  , c.solucion , c.estado , l.idcliente , l.nombre , l.ncuenta , l.nombredec , l.ciudad , l.direccion , l.telefono , s.idseguimiento , s.seguimiento FROM caso c join cliente l on c.idcliente=l.idcliente join seguimiento s on c.id=s.idcaso where id = :id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me debería mostrar los dos "seguimientos" del caso 1 en el modal..

estoy intentando con este codigo y solo me manda un valor.

```js
$.each([respuesta.seguimiento], function( index, value ) {
                alert( index + ": " + value );
                
                     });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con la lógica que nos muestras estás pidiendo un `id` específico al backend y por lo mismo te responde el contenido de la fila con ese `id`. Si quisieras obtener todo el contenido de la tabla, podrías hacer que el backend, en caso de no recibir ID, te respondiera con un array de filas, sobre las cuales iterarías para llenar X formularios

Comment: y como haría esto amenadiel , soy novato aun no domino mucho la programación , te lo agradecería si me explicaras con ejemplos o algo así.

Comment: Efectivamente puedes hacerlo con `each`, pero no queda claro en la pregunta si quieres mostrar esos datos en una parte del formulario o si debes mostrar `n` formularios por cada registros que venga de la base de datos. Como dice @amenadiel, con el código que comparte tampoco puede verse si los datos que estás enviando del servidor son todos los que quieres o si vienen filtrados. Es necesario que aclares esos puntos en la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: quiero mostrar el campo "seguimiento" en cada modal por el id , si te fijas arriba en la imagen hay un input text con un valor de 1 que es el "id" de la tabla "caso" y en la foto de la tabla el "idcaso" es la foranea en la tabla "seguimiento"  de este lo que quiero es mostrar en cada modal los seguimientos por "id"  , que en la imagen sale "examplito" y quiero que me salga Examplito y big bank que son seguimiento del "idcaso" = 1.

Comment: @JOHANALEXISMORENOGUISAO Tu problema está del lado del servidor, la consulta que prepara el valor devuelto debe ofrecer la información que deseas mostrar. ¿Cómo construyes la respuesta que devuelves? Edita tu pregunta mostrando el código

Comment: Sí sí, veo `examplito` en algo que parece un `textarea` y que imagino es el `textarea` con `id="seguirme"`. De todos modos no has respondido a algo que yo creo es importante: ¿lo que quieres mostrar con el `each` es en esa parte solamente, en el `textarea`?  Ni tampoco has indicado algo que ya tres usuarios te hemos pedido: ¿cómo es el código que trae los datos del servidor? ¿En qué viene la parte de `examplito` en un array, en una clave de un json donde además vienen los datos del usuario?

Comment: ¿lo que quieres mostrar con el each es en esa parte solamente, en el textarea? R// la idea que tengo es mostrarlos en un label o algo así en este caso son dos campos y quiero mostrar ambos.   ¿cómo es el código que trae los datos del servidor? R// ahí esta la consulta y el ajax que trae los datos del servidor.

Comment: Es que no se entiende el contexto. Debes decir qué datos traes del servidor. Si traes todos los datos del formulario que muestras en la imagen, y cómo vienen esos datos. Supongo que vienen en un JSON con varias claves y que una clave sería lo que dices de `examplito` en forma de array. Es que ni siquiera se sabe cómo habría que aplicar el `each` si en una parte de la respuesta que viene del servidor, si en toda la respuesta, etc. No sé si me entiendes. Es necesario que seas claro explicando el contexto.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que imprime un `console.log(respuesta);` y así vemos qué es lo que viene del servidor exactamente?

Comment: El ajax me trae toda la información del caso  , que con el id del caso , idcliente , falla etc.... , lo que quiero imprimir en el MODAL donde estoy "pintando" la información del caso es los seguimientos que tiene dicho caso, en este caso "Examplito" y "Big Bank" son seguimientos del caso con ID = 1 , ya plasme la consulta y el resultado que me trae , solamente quiero mostrar esos  campos en cada modal con su respectivo id.   , console.log(respuesta); no me trae nada.

Comment: No cuadra que no te traiga nada y más arriba dices que sí te muestra datos, pero uno solo en vez de dos. ¿Dónde pusiste el `console.log`?  ¿Abriste la consola de Javascript en las opciones de desarrollo del navegador para revisar los datos que arroja `console.log`?

Comment: Sí en la consola de inspeccionar elemento puse el console.log y no me trae nada .

Comment: ¿Y cómo dices que con esto sí te imprime datos `$.each([respuesta.seguimiento], function( index, value ) {` ?  No puede ser entonces que `console.log(respuesta);` no muestre nada.  ¿Lo pusiste dentro del `done`?

Comment: Ahí te añadi lo que me trae $.each([respuesta.seguimiento], function( index, value ) {
                alert( index + ": " + value );
                
                     });  .